# php query, work only one at time

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, filter

I using this `php filter` for search box in my wp website.
I know this is wrong because the filter show me only the last query, how I can write the code in the way both query work?

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
           $query->set('post_type', 'post');
           $query->set('post_type', 'course');
       }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `$query` every time on the last `post_type` which is of(course) wrong .

Change it to

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
          $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'course' ) );
       }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a beginner in php and haven't think to use array! Now i have learn thank you!